# Missing tables with twocolumn

Tags: two-column, landscape

Sometimes tables go missing when I change the orientation from portrait to landscape in a scrartcl document and use the `\twocolumn` environment. For example, if I want to display some tables from https://www.reed.edu/academic_support/pdfs/qskills/latexcheatsheet.pdf

```
\documentclass[DIV=14]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape}
\recalctypearea
\twocolumn
\section{Symbols (in \emph{math} mode)}

\subsection{The basics}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\emph{description}          & \emph{command}        & \emph{output} \\
addition                    & \verb!+!              & \(+ \) \\
subtraction                 & \verb!-!              & \(- \) \\
plus or minus               & \verb!\pm!            & \(\pm \) \\
multiplication (times)      & \verb!\times!         & \(\times \) \\
multiplication (dot)        & \verb!\cdot!          & \(\cdot \) \\
division symbol             & \verb!\div!           & \(\div \) \\
division (slash)            & \verb!/!              & \(/\) \\
circle plus                 & \verb!\oplus!         & \(\oplus \) \\
circle times                & \verb!\otimes!        & \(\otimes \) \\
equal                       & \verb!=!              & \(=\) \\
not equal                   & \verb!\ne!            & \(\ne \) \\
less than                   & \verb!<!              & \(<\) \\
greater than                & \verb!>!              & \(>\) \\
less than or equal to       & \verb!\le!            & \(\le \) \\
greater than or equal to    & \verb!\ge!            & \(\ge \) \\
approximately equal to      & \verb!\approx!        & \(\approx \) \\
infinity                    & \verb!\infty!         & \(\infty \) \\
dots                        & \verb!1,2,3,\ldots!   & \(1,2,3,\ldots \) \\
dots                        & \verb!1+2+3+\cdots!   & \(1+2+3+\cdots \) \\
fraction                    & \verb!\frac{a}{b}!    & \(\frac{a}{b}\) \\
square root                 & \verb!\sqrt{x}!       & \(\sqrt{x}\) \\
\(n\)th root                & \verb!\sqrt[n]{x}!    & \(\sqrt[n]{x}\) \\
exponentiation              & \verb!a^b!            & \(a^{b}\) \\
subscript                   & \verb!a_b!            & \(a_{b}\) \\
absolute value              & \verb!|x|!            & \(|x|\) \\
natural log                 & \verb!\ln(x)!         & \(\ln(x)\) \\
logarithms                  & \verb!\log_{a}b!      & \(\log_{a}b\) \\
exponential function        & \verb!e^x=\exp(x)!    & \(e^{x}=\exp(x)\) \\
degree                      & \verb!\deg(f)!        & \(\deg(f)\) \\
\end{tabular}

\subsection{Functions}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\emph{description}  & \emph{command}        & \emph{output}\\
maps to             & \verb!\to!            & \(\to \) \\
composition         & \verb!\circ!          & \(\circ \) \\
piecewise           & \verb!|x|=!           & \multirow{5}{*}{\(\displaystyle |x|=\begin{cases}x&x\ge 0\\-x&x<0\end{cases}\)}\\
function            &\verb|\begin{cases}|   &\\ 
                    &\verb!x & x\ge 0\\!    &\\ 
                    &\verb!-x & x<0!        &\\ 
                    &\verb!\end{cases}!     &
\end{tabular}


\subsection{Greek and Hebrew letters}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\emph{command}      & \emph{output}     &\emph{command}     & \emph{output}\\
\verb!\alpha!       & \(\alpha \)       &\verb!\tau!        & \(\tau \) \\
\verb!\beta!        & \(\beta \)        &\verb!\theta!      & \(\theta \) \\
\verb!\chi!         & \(\chi \)         &\verb!\upsilon!    & \(\upsilon \) \\
\verb!\delta!       & \(\delta \)       &\verb!\xi!         & \(\xi \) \\
\verb!\epsilon!     & \(\epsilon \)     &\verb!\zeta!       & \(\zeta \) \\
\verb!\varepsilon!  & \(\varepsilon \)  &\verb!\Delta!      & \(\Delta \) \\
\verb!\eta!         & \(\eta \)         &\verb!\Gamma!      & \(\Gamma \) \\
\verb!\gamma!       & \(\gamma \)       &\verb!\Lambda!     & \(\Lambda \) \\
\verb!\iota!        & \(\iota \)        &\verb!\Omega!      & \(\Omega \) \\
\verb!\kappa!       & \(\kappa \)       &\verb!\Phi!        & \(\Phi \) \\
\verb!\lambda!      & \(\lambda \)      &\verb!\Pi!         & \(\Pi \) \\
\verb!\mu!          & \(\mu \)          &\verb!\Psi!        & \(\Psi \) \\
\verb!\nu!          & \(\nu \)          &\verb!\Sigma!      & \(\Sigma \) \\
\verb!\omega!       & \(\omega \)       &\verb!\Theta!      & \(\Theta \) \\
\verb!\phi!         & \(\phi \)         &\verb!\Upsilon!    & \(\Upsilon \) \\
\verb!\varphi!      & \(\varphi \)      &\verb!\Xi!         & \(\Xi \) \\
\verb!\pi!          & \(\pi \)          &\verb!\aleph!      & \(\aleph \) \\
\verb!\psi!         & \(\psi \)         &\verb!\beth!       & \(\beth \) \\
\verb!\rho!         & \(\rho \)         &\verb!\daleth!     & \(\daleth \) \\
\verb!\sigma!       & \(\sigma \)       &\verb!\gimel!      & \(\gimel \)
\end{tabular}


\subsection{Set theory}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\emph{description}  & \emph{command}        & \emph{output} \\
set brackets        & \verb|\{1,2,3\}|      & \( \{1,2,3\} \) \\
element of          & \verb|\in|            & \(\in \) \\
not an element of   & \verb|\notin|         & \(\not\in \) \\
subset of           & \verb|\subset|        & \(\subset \) \\
subset of           & \verb|\subseteq|      & \(\subseteq \) \\
not a subset of     & \verb|\not\subset|    & \(\not\subset \) \\
contains            & \verb|\supset|        & \(\supset \) \\
contains            & \verb|\supseteq|      & \(\supseteq \) \\
union               & \verb|\cup|           & \(\cup \) \\
intersection        & \verb|\cap|           & \(\cap \) \\
big union           & \verb|\bigcup_{n=1}^{10}A_n| & \(\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^{10}A_{n}\) \\
big intersection    & \verb|\bigcap_{n=1}^{10}A_n| & \(\displaystyle \bigcap_{n=1}^{10}A_{n}\) \\
empty set           & \verb|\emptyset|      & \(\emptyset \) \\
power set           & \verb|\mathcal{P}|    & \(\mathcal{P} \) \\
minimum             & \verb|\min|           & \(\min \) \\
maximum             & \verb|\max|           & \(\max \) \\
supremum            & \verb|\sup|           & \(\sup \) \\
infimum             & \verb|\inf|           & \(\inf \) \\
limit superior      & \verb|\limsup|        & \(\limsup \) \\
limit inferior      & \verb|\liminf|        & \(\liminf \) \\
closure             & \verb|\overline{A}|   & \(\overline{A} \)
\end{tabular}

\KOMAoptions{paper=portrait}
\recalctypearea
\onecolumn
\end{document}
```

The last section goes missing in the pdf output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: interesting. \recalctypearea looses the page. Add `\clearpage` before the KOMAoptions command.

Comment: I added an issue in the bug tracker: https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/tickets/28/

Comment: The bug will be resolved in the next KOMA version.

Comment: thats nice to know. thanks! is there some way I can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in KOMA: it uses `\newpage` which in two column mode only switch to the next column and not the next page.

It will be resolved in the next version.